# Update Tkinter panel over time

Tags: python, tkinter

I have Tkinter panels that I want to update over time. The main file executes a method on an imported class to draw the Tkinter panel and I want it to execute 5 times every second.

Here is the main script which calls the method to create the panel:

```
# Script to control updating the display
from tkinter import *
from settings import Settings
from main_panel import Main
import time


# Creates window
root = Tk()
root.configure(background = 'black')

# Establish settings variable
settings = Settings()

# Create panel class with settings
Main = Main(settings)

# Call panel function to create itself
Main.create(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the method which creates the Tkinter panels:

```
def create(self,root):
    current = self.get_current_status()
    self.draw_icons(root,current)
    self.draw_days(root,current)
    self.draw_temps(root,current)
    self.draw_status(root,current)
```

Where do I do the 'root.after' call to have the panels update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not provided enough code for a customized example, so here's a minimalist example of using `root.after()`:

```
from tkinter import *

def update_counter():
    counter = label_variable.get()

    if counter > 0:
        label_variable.set(counter - 1)
        root.after(1000, update_counter)

root = Tk()

label_variable = IntVar()
label_variable.set(10)
Label(root, textvariable=label_variable, width=10).pack()

root.after(1000, update_counter)

root.mainloop()
```

Hopefully this will give you an idea of how to incorporate `root.after()` into your own code.